# Random Image issue

Tags: php, html, css, image

I'm having some difficulty writing this code in php. I want to create a random image not for background which I learn from my previous thread but I want to learn how to create a random image. Here is what I got so far I only did the array and the html but my php code is incomplete:

```
//Random Image PHP
  $images = array(array("image 1" => "caption 1"),
                  array("image 2" => "caption 2"),
                  array("image 3" => "caption 3");

//HTML
<div class="image-with-caption">
<img src="image 1/<?php echo $file; ?>.jpg" /> 
<p id="caption"><?php echo $caption; ?></p> 
</div>
```

I appreciate any explanation & examples.

Comment: Do you want to create image, or just want to display image randomly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
  //Random Image PHP
  $images = array(array("image_1","caption 1"),
                  array("image_2","caption 2"),
                  array("image_3","caption 3"));
  $r = mt_rand(0,count($images)-1);
?>
//HTML
<div class="image-with-caption">
<img src="images/<?php echo $images[$r][0]; ?>.jpg" /> 
<p id="caption"><?php echo $images[$r][1]; ?></p> 
</div>
```

Comment: Hi GOsha, Thanks for the reply and example. I will test it out and see how it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 


//Random Image PHP
  $images = array();
  $images[0]['image'] = "image 1";
  $images[0]['caption'] = "image 1";
  $images[1]['image'] = "image 2";
  $images[1]['caption'] = "caption 2";
  $images[2]['image'] = "image 3";
  $images[2]['caption'] = "caption 3";

    $rand_index = mt_rand(0,2);

?>


//HTML
<div class="image-with-caption">

<img src="image 1/<?php echo $images[$rand_index]['image']."?".time(); ?>" /> 
<p id="caption"><?php echo $images[$rand_index]['caption']; ?></p> 

</div>
```

Comment: Hi Mit, Thanks for the reply and example. I will test it out and see how it works. Thanks!

Comment: Hi Mit, Thanks for the code, it's what I'm looking for. I appreciated you taking time to write this. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It probably isn't necessary to have the arrays within an array, but if you want to do it this way you could try:

```php
//Random Image PHP
$images = array(array("image1" => "caption 1"),
                array("image2" => "caption 2"),
                array("image3" => "caption 3"));

$image_key = array_rand($images);
$file = key($images[$image_key]);
$caption = $images[$image_key][$file];


//HTML
<div class="image-with-caption">
<img src="images/<?php echo $file; ?>.jpg" /> 
<p id="caption"><?php echo $caption; ?></p> 
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Incarnate, Thanks for the reply! Thanks for the example too. You're right about the array but I just want to see the differences between random background image and random image. I will test it out and see how it works. Thanks!